# when downloading windows 7 from msdn, how to confirm download is complete and correct?

Tags: windows-7, msdn

When you download software from msdn, in my case windows 7, how can I confirm that the download completed and is not corrupted?

I have tried downloading 2-3 times now, and the installation always screws up in the middle.

I downloaded a 64-bit version of windows 7 that works fine.  I now wanted to put w7 on my older computer, and its 32bit, and the install always failed. (installing the 64-bit on the same computer worked fine).

It would be great if I can at least confirm/validate that the file I downloaded was in good form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The msdn site (at least the one I have access to) publishes sha-1 sums of the disk .iso files.  (Reveal it by clicking the details button).  Get a sha-1 checksumming program and run that on your down loaded file.  I use sha1sum in my cygwin window.  There [are](http://www.labtestproject.com/win/sha1sum.exe.html) [others](http://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-announce/2004q4/000184.html).

Now you know the disk image is good.  Then set your image burning software (nero, roxio, whatever) to verify and you should producing good disks every time.